# Can a PHP file reflectively know the hash of itself?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I have a requirement to see if a file has been altered - is it possible to have a hash "know" what the hash is after the hash and then insert it into the code?

I guess what I am talking about is rather odd, but it may be possible by creating deliberate collisions.

Here is a pseudo code

EG:

```
FILE1)#
 _______ 
|<?php
|  require("someRequire.php");
|  checkThisFilesHashEquals(originPathName,"QJFOQOFJEQWOFHWEGHWG");
|
```

and therefore FILE1 itself's hash is "QJFOQOFJEQWOFHWEGHWG" because `checkThisFilesHashEquals(originPathName)` does in fact check that the hash of originPathName does in fact equal "QJFOQOFJEQWOFHWEGHWG"

Has anyone heard of anyone doing this? Using collisions to somehow self hash a file?

Comment: md5_file could be of use http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php if that's what you're trying to test against.

Comment: You can load the value of the hash through another file and include the other file... I don't think that would affect the hash, if you changed the other file

Comment: it's the reflection I am looking for.. it's almost like a deliberate collision ie. the `md5_file(myfile)` and the CONTENTS of `myfile` are the same

Comment: @Hallur this is the only way I can think of, but all you need to do is edit the "other file" to fake the incident

Comment: I don't know of any functions, but the only way I can think of this moment, of changing the md5 to become a certain value, is using a program to keep adding comments at the end of the file, until the desired md5 value is achieved...

Comment: you'd need to do a comparison `if` against both. If any file is altered from the original, the hash will be different. I believe this answers the question; *correct?* @MrHeelis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PoC || GTFO 14](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/pocorgtfo14.pdf) contains its own MD5 hash, and demonstrates the code necessary to pull off such a feat.

Comment: thank you! this is something I am still working on believe it or not

Comment: These are called **quines** (singular: quine) if you need help researching them.